# Alternative ways of saying "from start to finish" of a book

Tags: phrase-requests

I am trying to express something along the lines of:

> [...] where the visitor can read entire books from start to finish.

In Norwegian we say "fra perm til perm", which roughly would translate to something like "from hardback to hardback" indicating that the first hardback is the beginning of the book, and the second hardback if the last page.

Is there any way to express something like this in English?

Comment: *cover to cover*, *beginning to end*, *front to back*,...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In English, the corresponding expression is *from cover to cover*:

> read all the way through from the beginning to the end

<sub>(source: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from-cover-to-cover))</sub>

Comment: Of course. That was simple. Thank you :) I just registered at this site, so I have to wait another 8 minutes before I can accept your answer. I'll do it as soon as I can.

Comment: You're welcome (also to this site!). You can't accept an answer within the first *x* minutes after posting the question - this has nothing to do with your recent registration.